# Android Checkbox Preference to change Entry Value

Tags: android, checkbox, android-preferences, android-spinner

I have a `preferences` consisting of a `checkbox` and a `spinner`.
The spinner has a `android:entryvalues` attribute,
 I need to know **how to set when the checkbox value is true to change the entry values?**

Preference.Xml

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<PreferenceCategory 
    android:title="Preferences"
    android:key="first_category">


    <ListPreference 
        android:key="news_feed"
        android:title="Scout.org News Feeds"
        android:summary="Please Select which news feed you would like to be received..."
        android:defaultValue="1" 
        android:entries="@array/News_Feed_Title"
        android:entryValues="@array/newsfeed"
        android:dialogTitle="Scout.org News Feeds"
        android:dialogIcon="@drawable/ic_rss"   

        />
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="french"
        android:title="News Feed &amp; Library Language"
        android:summaryOff="@string/frenchblurb"
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:summaryOn="French Enabled"
        android:enabled="false"
    />


</PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: You are saying you want different lists on the spinner, according to the value of the checkbox? For example, check box = true, values on the spinner A, B, C, and for false  D, E, F?

Comment: @NunoGonçalves  No, check box = false android:entryValues="@array/newsfeed"

Comment: No check box = true android:entryValues="@array/newsfeed2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your entry values changes dynamically according to the value of the check box, then you can't set them as a resource on the xml file. You have to do that on the activity dynamically. So, get a reference to your check box on the, add it `setOnCheckedChangeListener` and then, there change the contents of the list. I think it's the only way for you to do it.